# how to calculate the time taken for the image to be loaded in the uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, ios4

How to calculate the time taken for the image to be loaded in the uiimageview. I use this code on a button click

```
-(IBAction)loadImage:(id)sender
{
    //Using block to create image view through NSOperationQueue
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperationWithBlock: ^{

    //Create image view and adding it to the view
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 375)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow_Red_Parrot.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    }];
}
```

I wanted to calculate the time taken from the click to image loaded on the image view. Can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you should only do UIKit stuff on the main thread. Secondly, you probably aren't going to get any accurate information from this. The image data will be loaded in a core animation transaction which will not occur at the same time as assigning the image view's image or even adding it as a subview.

Answer (score 2):

Before starting the operation, add:

```
NSDate *startDate=[NSDate date];
```

after the operation ended, add:

```
NSDate *endDate=[NSDate date];
double ellapsedSeconds=[endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
```